# How do we generalize words like 'a couple', 'a few', 'a pair', 'a pile of'?

Tags: terminology

I recall that there's a word for words like abovementioned, it probably derives from 'count', but I can't quite remember how do we call words that work with countables. Could anybody help me with that?

Scheme:

```
a pair         of boots
```

`↑               ↑`

`what I look for;  countable`

Comment: Do you mean synonyms? Those are phrases not words.

Comment: I mean the word that precedes countable. There are many of those: a bouquet, a bunch of, etc. There's a word for these words

Comment: I'm not sure there is a word to designate various **groups of things**. "of* just means relating to or belonging to. A group of friends, a bunch of flowers.

Comment: quantifiers? Classifiers? Measure words?

Comment: Actually it derives from a Latin word for counting - _quantity_. The technical term is **Quantifiers**. They indicate the quantity of something. They answer the question _How much/many?_ Quantifiers are a form of Determiner, and occur with articles and other determiners, before the adjectives. which are before the nouns, in an English noun phrase.

Comment: @jlawler That’s not from a Latin word for counting. It’s from a Latin word meaning ‘how much’. And quantifiers are a broader category than just these: _some_, _every_, _no_ are all quantifiers too.

Comment: Indeed, they're all broader categories. But this asked what you call that kind of word. And certainly "how much" involves the activity of quantifying, if not actually counting count nouns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer was given by jlawler:

> Actually it derives from a Latin word for counting - quantity. The technical term is **Quantifiers**. They indicate the quantity of something. They answer the question How much/many? Quantifiers are **a form of Determiner**, and occur with articles and other determiners, before the adjectives. which are before the nouns, in an English noun phrase.

Thank you all for your cooperation :)